# DIAC/TRIAC heater control suddenly switches to max power after a short period

Tags: power-electronics, triac, diac

I am trying to build a heating mantle and I decided to use a DIAC/TRIAC pair to control the power, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWiHY9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I realize that there are more efficient designs such as zero-crossing detection and using a PID controller, but I decided that this design was a good compromise between cost and potential for learning moments.  Here is a list of the parts that I used:

- Potentiometer: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/cts-electrocomponents/026TB32R253B1A1/203781
- DIAC: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/stmicroelectronics/DB4/1037921
- TRIAC: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/littelfuse-inc/2N6349AG/918275
- Capacitor: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/tdk-corporation/FG24X7S2A105KRT06/5811992 (I placed two in parallel and then put another one in series)
- Heatsink: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/aavid-thermal-division-of-boyd-corporation/530002B02500G/1216384

I put it together on a perf board and it didn't explode, which was a good sign.  However, trying to shift the potentiometer and change the power running through the heater, I would get very jumpy results.  It would be okay up to an RMS of 40 volts or so across the heater, but it would then jump to 112 volts RMS.  I first thought it was the potentiometer, but I checked through its resistance range and it was fine.  I then thought it was just really sensitive to different resistances and decided to place another 27kOhm resistor in parallel with the potentiometer to allow for a very slow change in total resistance.  This went against the results of my simulation, in which changing the potentiometer would lead to smooth changes in power, but I tried it anyway.  At this point, I was just trying to get the power output to be stable and didn't bother fiddling with the potentiometer.  Placing the extra resistor in parallel did allow me to get 60 volts RMS across the heating element, but strange behavior would follow.  It would be stable for a minute or so, but it would then jump back to the 112 volts RMS.  I then thought that this happened because of parasitic inductances but this also doesn't make any sense, as it would work for a while and the inductance would only really be a problem on start-up.  I then thought parts were overheating, but touching everything right after the jump didn't find anything wrong, and everything was still around room temp.  Does anyone know what could be happening here?  Did I just get a bad DIAC or TRIAC?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you determine your pot value? Seems about 1/10 the value it should be.

Comment: 100V caps for a 120V circuit? And a metal shaft pot?

Comment: @Kartman, yeah, I already had some parts from earlier projects but I made sure to place two of the capacitors in series.  I also insulated the pot with some electrical tape.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I used a falstad simulation to ball park the resistances needed, and putting it together I was able to get it to a point of no current passing through the heating element.